# does phagocytosis dependent on opsonization?

Tags: physiology, immunity

does phagocytotic activity of macrophages and neutrophils depends on opsonization by IGg (antibody) and C3 complex,if it does, so then why macrophages and neutrophils are categorized in Innate immune defense system (despite the interference of antibody).

and if it is not dependent so why macrophages act as antigen presenting cells to make antibodies, while they lysed it and fragmented it (the pathogen) on it's surface by it's own,so what is the need for it to make antibodies while the innate system can handle it alone?

Answer (score 2):

Well, phagocytosis does not depend on opsonization, but it works better with it because the macrophages can detect the intruders more easily, but the secondary inmune response with IgG depends on the work of the APC cells, so let`s say a bacteria gets in your body for the first time, it can get phagocytated by a macrophage that will after present the parts on his MHC II to start the secondary inmune response.

Comment: so what's the benefit of activating acquired immune system while the macrophages  can lys and kill it?